# How to print SparseTensor contents in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

For quick debugging purposes, I'm trying to print out the SparseTensor I've just initialized.

The built-in print function just says it's a SparseTensor object, and tf.Print() gives an error. The error statement does print the contents of the object, but not in a way that shows the actual entries (unless it's telling me it's empty, there's some :0s I don't know the significance of).

```
rows = tf.Print(rows, [rows])

TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("SparseTensor/indices:0", shape=(6, 2), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("SparseTensor/values:0", shape=(6,), dtype=float32), dense_shape=Tensor("SparseTensor/dense_shape:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Answer (score 7):

### Way 0: Run the SparseTensor and print the result

Running the graph (in this case just the SparseTensor object) returns a SparseTensorValue object which prints in the same format as the call used to initialize the SparseTensor, which is ultimately what I wanted.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  rows = sess.run(rows)
  print(rows)
```

### Way 1: Use Print after conversion to dense matrix

To use the Print function, I could convert to a dense matrix in my case. But Print only executes when you run the graph:

```
rows = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(rows)
rows = tf.Print(rows, [rows], summarize=100)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(rows)
```

Note the "summarize"--the default setting just printed out zeroes since it's getting the first few entries of a sparse matrix represented in dense form!

### Way 2: Use tf.test.TestCase

I found out that the TestCase.evaluate method gives me the kind of nice format I want, the same as Way 0 above:

```
print(str(self.evaluate(rows)))
```

Outputs e.g.:

```
SparseTensorValue(indices=array([[1, 2],
   [1, 7],
   [1, 8],
   [2, 2],
   [3, 4],
   [3, 5]]), values=array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], dtype=float32), dense_shape=array([4, 9]))
```

Answer (score 3):

You're seeing this error because SparseTensor is not really a Tensor, it's a MetaTensor that wraps 3 dense tensors.

Try using print() on your SparseTensor and you'll see the internal details:

```
indices=Tensor(…), values=Tensor(…), dense_shape=Tensor(…))
```

You can print any of these "internal" tensors using tf.Print. For example, tf.Print(my_sparse_tensor.values, [my_sparse_tensor.values]) will succeed.

The SparseTensor documentation describes the internal data structure:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/SparseTensor

TensorFlow represents a sparse tensor as three separate dense tensors: indices, values, and dense_shape. In Python, the three tensors are collected into a SparseTensor class for ease of use. If you have separate indices, values, and dense_shape tensors, wrap them in a SparseTensor object before passing to the ops below.

Concretely, the sparse tensor SparseTensor(indices, values, dense_shape) comprises the following components, where N and ndims are the number of values and number of dimensions in the SparseTensor, respectively:

indices: A 2-D int64 tensor of dense_shape [N, ndims], which specifies the indices of the elements in the sparse tensor that contain nonzero values (elements are zero-indexed). For example, indices=[[1,3], [2,4]] specifies that the elements with indexes of [1,3] and [2,4] have nonzero values.

values: A 1-D tensor of any type and dense_shape [N], which supplies the values for each element in indices. For example, given indices=[[1,3], [2,4]], the parameter values=[18, 3.6] specifies that element [1,3] of the sparse tensor has a value of 18, and element [2,4] of the tensor has a value of 3.6.

dense_shape: A 1-D int64 tensor of dense_shape [ndims], which specifies the dense_shape of the sparse tensor. Takes a list indicating the number of elements in each dimension. For example, dense_shape=[3,6] specifies a two-dimensional 3x6 tensor, dense_shape=[2,3,4] specifies a three-dimensional 2x3x4 tensor, and dense_shape=[9] specifies a one-dimensional tensor with 9 elements.

The corresponding dense tensor satisfies:

```
dense.shape = dense_shape
dense[tuple(indices[i])] = values[i]
```

By convention, indices should be sorted in row-major order (or equivalently lexicographic order on the tuples indices[i]). This is not enforced when SparseTensor objects are constructed, but most ops assume correct ordering. If the ordering of sparse tensor st is wrong, a fixed version can be obtained by calling tf.sparse_reorder(st).

Example: The sparse tensor

```
SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 0], [1, 2]], values=[1, 2], dense_shape=[3, 4])
```

represents the dense tensor:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 2, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```